# Visual Studio Code clangd extension configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang

I am trying to integrate clangd with VS Code using vscode-clangd extension, but I am having problem with configuring include paths...

I created additional config in VS Code settings:

```
"clangd.path": "path_to_clangd/bin/clangd",
"clangd.arguments": [
    "-compile-commands-dir=path_to_commands/compile_commands.json"
]
```

but the extension reports lots of missing includes errors.

I have also tried:

```
    "-compile-commands-dir=path_to_commands"
```

but this also didn't work.

Does anyone knows how to configure this extension at all? I am unable to find any documentation at this point.

Regards

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't marked an answer as solution?

Answer (score 8):

Your path should be directory to compile_commands.json, not file, and you need to restart the clangd by the vscode-clangd extension

*settings.json*

```json
{
    "cmake.buildDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/debug",
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "-background-index",
        "-compile-commands-dir=debug"
    ],
}
```

*Restart*

1. change a bit of .clang-tidy file under your project root directory, if no, create one with something
2. the vscode-clangd will prompt you to restart the clangd
3. check the clangd process, it should something similar to

```
❯ ps -Af | grep clangd
awei     285478 282126  0 10:42 ?        00:00:03 /opt/llvm-10.0.0/bin/clangd -background-index -compile-commands-dir=debug
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my answer, it works:

```
    "clangd.path": "/Users/jiewang/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd/install/11.0.0/clangd_11.0.0/bin/clangd",
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "--compile-commands-dir=${workspaceFolder}/build",
        "--completion-style=detailed",
        "--header-insertion=never"
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the compile_commands.json has to be in the Folder root directory for the extension to find it.

I just add a symlink:

```
ln -s /path-to-build-dir/compile_commands.json /path-to-src-root-dir/
```